# J2ME Enterprise Applications

Tags: java, java-me

My company has an ERP solution which caters to the retail trade. Therefor besides the server side application we have a mobile client side application which runs on industrial PDAs.

Initially we had our entire application on the windows platform. But recently company is considering possibilities of porting the mobile application to java; primary reason being the application to be possible to run on a given high end PDA regardless of the operating system.

I find a limited number of java enterprise mobile applications. What are we to expect? Will this be a good move. If so what are the types of challenges we will face? Will the unavailability of a good mobile database technology for j2me (which I am not sure, please give me suggestions) be a problem? Besides the application logic we had earlier was an extremely memory intensive one. So will java mobile edition be able to handle this complexity or will we need to go with something like java CDC, since the PDAs are powerful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory limitation will be there as you are planning to port it in PDAs.

I would recommend you to go through the security arch. of java-me [You need to consider it]

Comment: Hi Jigar, Thanks for your quick answer. Is this doable? Is it possible for you to give me the names of some big j2me enterprise applications? Also in what you mentioned, memory is a hardware related issue correct? How will it affect the development technology? If we were successful with Windows mobile will this become a problem with j2me? Thanks again.

Comment: Please check [this](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/) , There are Nimbuzz and other famous app running on java-me, check the link and derive the feasibility

Comment: Hi Jigar, I greatly value your input for my question. I will go through the link as you've suggested. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Jigar, If you know please give me one or two open source projects which really implement j2me in an enterprise sense. Thanks again.